# Is Auto scaling process for Azure Chat bot application same as that of app service auto scaling?

Tags: azure, botframework, autoscaling

I am concerned about the load performance of my Chat bot deployed in Chat bot service.
If for my Bots in production, there is sudden load of huge number of users chatting simultaneously, will my Bot handle that load.
Do I need to consider special criteria for auto scaling different than app service

Comment: Can you please provide us with more information. Is your bot running on a Web App or on Azure Functions (App Service plan vs Consumption Plan? Is your bot C# or NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know that Bot Service provides two hosting plans for your bots: **App Service plan** and **Consumption plan**.

And Consumption plan scales automatically, even during periods of high load.

Besides, if you host your bot application with an specified App Service plan on Azure web app and you configured autoscaling for the plan, then your bot application and other apps in that plan are scaled out together based on the autoscale settings.

Answer (score 1):

As Fei Han mentioned above, [Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) provides two option based on [scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-how-to-scale?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json) and hosting capabilities: [App Service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview) and [Consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan).

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#scalability-best-practices) provides guidance to improve the performance and reliability of your serverless function apps.

The Consumption plan automatically allocates compute power when your code is running, scales out as necessary to handle load, and then scales down when code is not running. You don't have to pay for idle VMs and don't have to reserve capacity in advance.

With an App Service plan, you can manually scale out by adding more VM instances, or you can enable autoscale. And the other reason to consider this is, they support Linux.

You can decide by comparing both based on your business requirements. Hope this helps!!